# How do I use param arrays and declare a method accepting int values and displaying the sum as a double value using csharp?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static int add ( params int [ ] number )
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach ( int n in number )
        {
            sum=sum+n;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // passing three parameters
        Program conv = new Program();
        Console.Write("The sum of the given number is: ");
        Console.Write(add(1, 2, 3));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Current Output:** The sum of the given number is 6

**Expected Output:** The sum of the given number is 6.0

Comment: Current Output: The sum of the given number is 6.

Comment: Expected Output: The sum of the given number is 6.0

Comment: just change `int` to `double` in your function

Comment: If you wish to add clarifications to your question, please *[edit]* it. There should be no need to add *comments* for this sort of thing

Comment: Convert to `double` first like `double x = add(1, 2, 3)` and then use `Console.Write("{0:0.0}", x);`.

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever it's my first time using this site.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto that works, but what if I want it to accept any point zero digit? should I then just edit the Console.Write to Console.Write("{0:0.0}"); because if I do that the output gives me 65 instead of 6.5

Comment: I figured it out, thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto, you've been a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

```
static double Add(params int[] number)
{
    var sum = 0;
    foreach (var n in number)
    {
        sum = sum + n;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in question that your params are int and you need output in double, the best way is to change format while printing result to console. I think there is no need to change anything else and no type casting is needed.

```
class Program
{
    static int add ( params int [ ] number )
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach ( int n in number )
        {
            sum=sum+n;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // passing three parameters
        //Program conv = new Program(); // NO NEED OF THIS.
        Console.Write("The sum of the given number is: ");
        Console.Write("{0:0.0}", add(1, 2, 3)); // CHANGE

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of 2 things here. Since your return type is int, you will always get integer value i.e. 6.

To get 6.0, you need to change the return type to double and while returning the result cast the value to double.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

You can return as formatted string and Use double instead of Int

```
class Program
{
    static string add(params int[] number)
    {
        double sum = 0.0f;
        foreach (double n in number)
        {
            sum = sum + n;
        }
        return string.Format("{0:N2}" ,sum);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // passing three parameters
        Program conv = new Program();
        Console.Write("The sum of the given number is: ");
        Console.Write(add(1, 2, 3));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image: See Screenshot as Answer]

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Program
{
    static int add(params int[] number)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int n in number)
        {
            sum = sum + n;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("The sum of the given number is: ");
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0:N1}", (add(1, 2, 3))));
        //Output : The sum of the given number is: 6.0
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put some explanation why you converted to double? Is there any need of doing so?

Comment: @GaurangDave, If you need to only print the value, no need to convert.

Comment: Still your code is returning compilation error? One closing bracket is still missing? Did you really test it? I edited you answer and corrected it.

Comment: @GaurangDave, Yes above code tested, copy the code properly and test.

Comment: I tested it that is why I told you that it was returning error. I edited your answer and correct it. THanks :)